# How to open a link in a new window with javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Basic Javascript question: How to open a new window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794674/basic-javascript-question-how-to-open-a-new-window)

I have such a link wrapped in a div:

```
<div class="sponsor" target="_blank" onclick="location.href='http://www.sponsor.com"></div>
```

Actually what I need is this link to open in a new window. At this point it opens in the same page. Thanks!

Comment: Why is it a div? Why not just put an `a` tag inside the div? That way the target attribute will actually work (despite being deprecated).

Comment: Any specific reason why you are using a div and not an anchor tag. I don't think you can have the target blank behavior with div elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.open('http://www.sponsor.com','_blank');
```